# Change Windows password when in multiple RDP

Tags: remote-desktop

I run a VM on my local PC to sandbox a VPN connection, I then RDP from this VM into the PC I use for work. I need to change the password but CTRL+ALT+END brings up the menu for the *1st* VM.

How can I change the password (and access the CTRL+ALT-DEL menu) when in such a 'recursive' RDP scenario?

Comment: What RDP client are you using exactly?

Comment: The standard Windows one (I don't know the version, but it probably varies between machines)

Comment: If thats the case there should be a drop down menu option to send the CTRL-ALT-DEL command.

Comment: @Ramhound for some reason, no. The first RDP has those menu options on the top bar, but the 2nd - the one on their computer - just has minimise/pin/etc

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Open "On screen keyboard" (osk.exe)

Send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> by mouse-clicking each on key individually, in the most nested RDP session.

---

If that does not work try holding Ctrl+Alt on your keyboard and clicking Del in OSK in the the RDP session

Comment: I'll try this. Is there any way to bring up the CTRL+ALT+DEL dialog other than using the keyboard shortcut, I wonder? Like some executable I can run directly?

Comment: I had do to the 2nd version in your comment... might be worth updating the answer. But it worked, thanks!

Comment: Answer updated. Glad it worked :). Sorry, I'm not aware of any means to bring up that screen without sending the keystrokes.

Comment: I got "Could not start On-Screen Keyboard" when I attempted to open OSK, so I found this alternative method: https://superuser.com/a/1515453/68728

Comment: I also got the "Could not start On-Screen Keyboard" message. I got my password changed by doing the following: https://superuser.com/a/1547031/345473

Answer (score 9):

If you have a nested RDP session and the on-screen keyboard is disabled, you can try opening up PowerShell and running the following command:

```
(New-Object -COM Shell.Application).WindowsSecurity()
```

Then enter in your existing password, new password, and hit enter.

Answer (score 3):

You can always open a "CMD" command prompt on the VM and reset the password via command line.

When you get the C:\ prompt, you would type something like  "net user administrator Ch@rli3"
and that would change the administrator account's password to "Ch@rli3".

Comment: I don't want to change the local administrator account, it's a network login on their domain. Unless the two are synonomous?

Comment: "[Only administrators](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/149427) can change domain passwords at the Windows command prompt. "

Answer (score 2):

Open Run type in lusrmgr.msc go to users, select your user account, right click your user account select set password, set password, logout. Login with new password. Done.

Comment: Note: don't do this. There is a difference between *"changing"* a password, and *"setting"* a password. If you *"set"* someone's password, they lose all access to encryption keys and saved passwords (which is right and correct - it prevents you from resetting their password and viewing all their encrypted stuff). When you ***change*** a password, Windows does the bookkeeping to ensure all the encrypted information is made available under the new password.

Answer (score 1):

StickyKeys can accomplish this:

1. Turn on StickyKeys (from *Control Panel > Ease of Access Center > Make the keyboard easier to use*) in the most nested RDP session.
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, then <kbd>Alt</kbd>, then <kbd>Del</kbd>