# Can't change network password from command line

Tags: windows-7, networking, command-line, passwords, active-directory

I have a previous question relating to how one can change a password of the 'bottom' client when recursively logged in to multiple RDP clients: [Change Windows password when in multiple RDP](https://superuser.com/questions/519283/change-windows-password-when-in-multiple-rdp)

One suggestion was to use the command line. However this isn't working. I need to change the network password for my user TheirDomain\Mr Boy:

> C:>net user "mr boy" MyNewPassword /domain The request will be
>   processed at a domain controller for domain *< redacted>*.
>
> System error 5 has occurred.
>
> Access is denied.

If I run the same thing without passing a new password, it works, displaying me information about my username.

I don't know what the DC is running - Active Directory probably on Win2k8 - but the PC is W7.

Any answer how to fix this specific issue, or the more general issue in the linked question, would be appreciated. I currently have no way of changing my password other than waiting for it to expire, when logging in will prompt/force me!

Answer (score 2):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/149427

> Only administrators can change domain passwords at the Windows command prompt.

It seems as a user you cannot do this

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to accomplish the password change from the command line, or is that only a requirement since you are in nested RDP sessions? If you save the following to a text file named ChangePassword.vbs, you can launch it from a command line and then change your password in the current RDP session:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.WindowsSecurity
```

Comment: this will get you the GUI of Windows to change the PW. (could also get it via virtual Keyboard in nested RDP session.